# Create a new column condition-wisely

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to figure out how to translate my Pandas-utilising function to PySpark.

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
+---+----+
|num| val|
+---+----+
|  1| 0.0|
|  2| 0.0|
|  3|48.6|
|  4|49.0|
|  5|48.7|
|  6|49.1|
|  7|74.5|
|  8|48.7|
|  9| 0.0|
| 10|49.0|
| 11| 0.0|
| 12| 0.0|
+---+----+
```

The code in the snippet below is fairly simple. It goes forwards till finds a non-zero value. If there is none of them it goes backwards for the same purpose

```
def next_non_zero(data,i,column):
    for j in range(i+1,len(data[column])):
        res = data[column].iloc[j]
        if res !=0:
            return res
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
        res = data[column].iloc[j]
        if res !=0:
            return res

def fix_zero(data, column):
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        if (row[column] == 0):
            data.at[i,column] = next_non_zero(data,i,column)
```

So as a result I expect to see

```
+---+----+
|num| val|
+---+----+
|  1|48.6|
|  2|48.6|
|  3|48.6|
|  4|49.0|
|  5|48.7|
|  6|49.1|
|  7|74.5|
|  8|48.7|
|  9|49.0|
| 10|49.0|
| 11|49.0|
| 12|49.0|
+---+----+
```

So I do understand that in PySpark I have to create a new column with the desired result and replace an existing column using withColumn() for example. However, I do not understand how to properly iterate through a DataFrame.

I am trying to use functions over Window:

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('num')
df = df.withColumn('new_val', F.when(df.val==0,F.lead(df.val).over(my_window)).
                                 otherwise(F.lag(df.val).over(my_window))
```

Obviously, it does not provide me with the desired result as it iterates only once.
So I tried to write some udf recursion like

```
def fix_zero(param):

    return F.when(F.lead(param).over(my_window)!=0,F.lead(param).over(my_window)).
                   otherwise(fix_zero(F.lead(param).over(my_window)))

spark_udf = udf(fix_zero, DoubleType())
df = df.withColumn('new_val', F.when(df.val!=0, df.val).otherwise(fix_zero('val')))
```

I got

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I suspect that this is because I pass into recursion not a row but a result of lead()
Anyway, I am totally stuck on this hurdle at this moment and would deeply appreciate any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way with Window to go through all preceeding (or all following rows) until you reach a non-null value.

So my first step was to replace all 0 values by null

Recreating your dataframe:

```
values = [
    (1, 0.0),
    (2,0.0),
    (3,48.6),
    (4,49.0),
    (5,48.7),
    (6,49.1),
    (7, 74.5),
    (8,48.7),
    (9,0.0),
   (10,49.0),
   (11,0.0),
   (12,0.0)
]  

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['num','val'])
```

Replacing 0s with null

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col
df= df.withColumn('val_null', when(col('val') != 0.0,col('val')))
```

Then define the windows, which combined with first and null, will allow us to get last non null value before row and first non null value after row

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import last,first,coalesce


windowForward = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
ffilled_column = last(df['val_null'], ignorenulls=True).over(windowForward)

windowBackward = Window.rowsBetween(Window.currentRow,Window.unboundedFollowing)
bfilled_column = first(df['val_null'], ignorenulls=True).over(windowBackward)

# creating new columns in df
df =df.withColumn('ffill',ffilled_column).withColumn('bfill',bfilled_column)

# replace null with bfill if bfill is not null otherwise fill with ffill
df =df.withColumn('val_full',coalesce('bfill','ffill'))
```

Using this technique we arrive at your expected output in column 'val_full'

```
+---+----+--------+-----+-----+--------+
|num| val|val_null|ffill|bfill|val_full|
+---+----+--------+-----+-----+--------+
|  1| 0.0|    null| null| 48.6|    48.6|
|  2| 0.0|    null| null| 48.6|    48.6|
|  3|48.6|    48.6| 48.6| 48.6|    48.6|
|  4|49.0|    49.0| 49.0| 49.0|    49.0|
|  5|48.7|    48.7| 48.7| 48.7|    48.7|
|  6|49.1|    49.1| 49.1| 49.1|    49.1|
|  7|74.5|    74.5| 74.5| 74.5|    74.5|
|  8|48.7|    48.7| 48.7| 48.7|    48.7|
|  9| 0.0|    null| 48.7| 49.0|    49.0|
| 10|49.0|    49.0| 49.0| 49.0|    49.0|
| 11| 0.0|    null| 49.0| null|    49.0|
| 12| 0.0|    null| 49.0| null|    49.0|
+---+----+--------+-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @fmarm. As far as I understand if I want to replace a value - change it to null. So I can deal with not only zeros but with highly deviated values as well. Right?

Comment: I wonder if such an approach is more effective than Pandas. Seems a bit cumbersome to me. Although, I am ready to admit that this is because of a lack of experience in Spark.

Comment: @EfYak Yes you could also replace high values with null. This approach will be more effective than Pandas if you have a big dataframe and you're not using Spark on local mode but on multiple clusters to benefit from parallelization. In particular, if your dataset cannot fit in memory, you will not be able to use pandas. Also note that in pyspark you should avoid using UDFs as your code will be very slow after this, pure Spark approach will always be faster.